# NinjectWebCommon Bindings in RegisterServices not working for me in WebApi

Tags: ninject, asp.net-web-api

I create a new ASP.NET Web API project. I then use nuget to pull Ninject.Web.Common, then I download and build Ninject.Web.WebApi from [here](https://github.com/remogloor/Ninject.Web.WebApi). Included it in the project. I added a service and the injection via constructor, setup binding (the debugger shows that the code actually hits the bind) but still throws this error:

```
Error activating IValueService
No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
Activation path:
  2) Injection of dependency IValueService into parameter valueService of constructor of type ValuesController
  1) Request for ValuesController

Suggestions:
  1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for IValueService.
  2) If the binding was defined in a module, ensure that the module has been loaded into the kernel.
  3) Ensure you have not accidentally created more than one kernel.
  4) If you are using constructor arguments, ensure that the parameter name matches the constructors parameter name.
  5) If you are using automatic module loading, ensure the search path and filters are correct.
```

Libraries in my project:

1. Ninject.dll
2. Ninject.Web.Common
3. Ninject.Web.Webapi
4. WebActivator

All ninject libraries are marked as version 3.

Here is the Code:

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(MvcApplication3.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivator.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(typeof(MvcApplication3.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Stop")]
namespace MvcApplication3.App_Start
{
using System;
using System.Web;

using Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper;

using Ninject;
using Ninject.Web.Common;

public static class NinjectWebCommon 
{
    private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the application
    /// </summary>
    public static void Start() 
    {
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
        DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
        bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the application.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Stop()
    {
        bootstrapper.ShutDown();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
    private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
        kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

        RegisterServices(kernel);
        return kernel;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Load your modules or register your services here!
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {

        kernel.Bind<IValueService>().To<ValueService>();
    }        
}

}
```

service:

```
public interface IValueService
{
    List<string> GetStrings();
}

public class ValueService : IValueService
{
    public List<string> GetStrings()
    {
        return new List<string>{"test", "test"};
    }
}
```

controller:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IValueService valueService;

    // GET /api/values
    public ValuesController(IValueService valueService)
    {
        this.valueService = valueService;
    }
}
```

The downloaded project sample from github works but not when I create a new project. Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just checked that there is no issue with this extension (at least not with the lastest MVC4 preview):

- Create a new MVC4 WEB Api project
- Nuget Install-Package Ninject.Web.WebAPI
- Change controller + add bindings

Your code looks good. There must be a problem somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know there was a nuget package. Did installing the package do something else to the project that I wouldn't do when manually including the dll?

Comment: I have no idea what you did. The package is not doing anything special.

Comment: How could this "Your code looks good. There must be a problem somewhere else." be the accepted answer?

Answer (score -1):

Do not bind directly in RegisterServices but first create a class from 
IDependencyResolver en add your bindings in AddBindings

example

See in book Pro ASP.NET MVC5 from Adam Freeman

Comment: Were you about to post an actual example? If so, it is missing. A book reference is an off-site resource, which should be (if inevitable) complete with chapter/footnote/etc.